# What does "We have posts flagged for moderator attention, perhaps you can help?" mean

Tags: bug, status-completed

Today H:SE has a cheery yellow bubble in the banner informing me that we have posts flagged for moderator attention.  The number in the bubble is "0" - so apparently we have 0 posts flagged for attention?  How can I help?

If the problem is that we have 0 posts flagged for attention, then I suppose I could help by creating a post that deserves moderator attention, but I'm not sure that is really the message I'm supposed to take away.

What message **should** I take from this?

Comment: I'm sure you'd be up to the task. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some types of flags are actionable by non-moderator trusted (aka high rep) users. See details here: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/what-to-do-with-flags-which-are-valid-but-not-for-earth-shatteringly-bad-content

You can also see these flags with this link: https://history.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged

You as a user may have enough rep to action those flags, though not nearly enough power compared to an actual mod (see screenshot of the options in the linked question). Most typically, you just escalate the flag to the moderator anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, [this was my bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189872/3) - fixed now.

Comment: may not have been a bad error; turns out that one of my other SE: sites _did_ have flags for review, so I saw a "1" in the bubble.  But the counter doesn't reset when I process the flag.